# How to update values in RecyclerView on onResume()?

Tags: android

I'm designing a news app in which I'm showing the news articles in a recyclerView. Now on clicking a news article I want to change its background color to indicate that the news item has been read.

For this, first I update a status field corresponding to the news article in my Firebase Database when the news is read. Then I check the value of this field in my recycler Adapter and change the background if the status is changed.

However since the adapter of the recyclerView is defined in the onCreateView of the fragment, the change does not take place immediately when I press the back button. Rather the changes occur when reopen the app since the onCreateView is called that time. So how do I update the adapter in onResume of the fragment and update  the recyclerView accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `onResume` method and call `notifyDataSetChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: It works but since the adapter is called again, it leads to duplicate values in the recyclerview. Any solution?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged refreshes the recyclerview according to listData reference which was used to initialize it. So check when you change the status data you are not creating duplicate entry for it.

Comment: @Sarthak You must reset your list before calling notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume() to avoid duplication.

Comment: @EKN clearing of whole list is unnecessary for change in single entry. What must be taken care of is that when the single entry is required to be changed use the position and passed dataList to get the reference of that single entry and change it status. So calling notifyDataSetChanged would only reflect changes on dataList and won't create duplicate entry.

Comment: @SarthakGrover Is every entry gets duplicated or only one which is changed?

Answer (score 4):

Initialize and set adapter from oncreateview();

Then you only need to update adapter data and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); form your onResume();

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(listofdata);
  yourRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
listofdata.clear();  //Reset before update adapter to avoid duplication of list
//update listofdata
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> add your codes to update data and notify Adapter

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
/// code to update data then notify Adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```